# CakePHP: Notice (1024): Element Not Found: Elements\8.ctp

Tags: cakephp

I've done blog by tutorial and stopped at [Deleting Posts](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/part-two.html) (all code is by this link), because has Notice (1024): Element Not Found: Elements\8.ctp ( 8 - id  of deleted record) when click Delete in table on index page. And record is really deleted in database. How to solve this notice? My version cakephp is 2.6.1.
Thanks.

```
 <?php
class PostsController extends AppController {
    public $helpers = array ('Html', 'Form', 'Session');
    public $components = array('Session');

    public function index() {
        $this->set('posts',$this->Post->find('all'));
    }

    public function view($id = null)
    {
        if (!$id)
        {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid Post'));
        }

        $post=$this->Post->findById($id);
        if (!$post) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid post'));
        }
        $this->set('post',$post);
    }

    public function add()
    {
        if ($this->request->is('post'))
        {
            $this->Post->create();
            if ($this->Post->save($this->request->data))
            {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your post has been saved'));
                return $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
            }
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to add your post'));
        }
    }

    public function edit($id = null)
    {
        if (!$id)
        {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid post'));
        }
        $post=$this->Post->findById($id);
        if (!$post)
        {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid post'));
        }

        if ($this->request->is(array('post','put')))
        {
            $this->Post->id=$id;
            if ($this->Post->save($this->request->data))
            {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your post has been updated'));
                return $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
            }
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to update your post'));
        }

        if (!$this->request->data)
        {
            $this->request->data=$post;
        }
    }

    public function delete($id)
    {
        if ($this->request->is('get'))
        {
            throw new MethodNotAllowedException();
        }
        if ($this->Post->delete($id))
        {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The post with id: %s has been deleted'),h($id));
            return $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
        }

        return $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
    }
}
```

// index.ctp

```
   <h1>Blog posts</h1>
    <?php
    echo $this->Html->link(
        'Add Post',array('controller'=>'posts','action'=>'add')
    );
    ?>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
            <th>Created</th>
        </tr>
        <?php foreach ($posts as $post): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $post['Post']['id'];?></td>
            <td>
                <?php
                    echo $this->Html->link($post['Post']['title'],array(
                        'controller' => 'posts',
                        'action' => 'view',
                        $post['Post']['id']
                    ));
                ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php
                    echo $this->Form->postLink(
                        'Delete',
                        array('action' => 'delete', $post['Post']['id']),
                        array('confirm' => 'Are you sure?')
                    );
                ?>
                <?php
                    echo $this->Html->link(
                        'Edit',
                        array('action' => 'edit', $post['Post']['id'])
                    );
                ?>
            </td>
            <td><?php echo $post['Post']['created']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php unset($post); ?>
    </table>
```

Comment: Provide your `index.ctp` code here.

Comment: The index.php won't help at all here... But the controller or view file.

Answer (score 0):

```
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('The post with id: %s has been deleted'),h($id));
```

the problem is here,
setFlash(__('The post with id: %s has been deleted'),h($id));

this should be,
setFlash(__('The post with id: %s has been deleted',h($id)));

Answer (score -1):

Because you **didn't** provide code (not smart if you want to get help), I *guess*  you're calling somewhere `$this->element($id);` in your view. The tutorial you've linked doesn't contain this method call anywhere. So you do something different.

Also read the error message, it tells you that it it missing a file called 8.ctp in your `app/View/Elements/ folder`. To figure out why is now up to you.

Comment: all code is equal by examples in tutorial. so i don't call ->element()

Comment: Then *something* is *somehow* magically calling `$this->element()`, the error message clearly states that. And by the way: There is a stack trace telling you from where it comes from, file and line so just look that up.

Comment: thanks. i download cakephp yesterday only, so i hope you say where i can read about this problem or you explain me. because it's difficult continue to read tutorial or api without understanding.  do you need more source?

Comment: Notice (1024): Element Not Found: Elements\9.ctp [CORE\Cake\View\View.php, line 425]

Comment: Sorry, I'm not going to explain you the *very basics* like a stack trace and what a notice exactly means in php, this is not specific to CakePHP but basic debugging in php (and other languages). Use Google to look that up, this is to broad to be answered here. There is as well official training offered http://training.cakephp.org/ but this is a paid service.

Comment: i mean  how to solve problem with Notice (1024): ... .there are several files with code from tutorial and you tell me to research the core.

Comment: I'm telling you (again) to *look at the stack trace*, it will tell you from where the notice comes from. If you don't know what that is look it up on Google. That's an example of a trace: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Tzh2B.png Click on the (notice) text and it will show it.